# Removing elements to sort array

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm looking for an algorithm to sort an array, but not by moving the values. Rather, I'd like to delete as few values as possible and end up with a sorted list. Basically I want to find the longest ascending sub-array.

To illustrate:

```
1 4 5 6 7 2 3 8
```

Should become (2 removes)

```
1 4 5 6 7 8
```

And not (5 removes)

```
1 2 3
```

I can see how I can do this in a naive way, i.e. by recursively checking both the 'remove' and 'dont remove' tree for each element. I was just wondering if there was a faster / more efficient way to do this. Is there a common go-to algorithm for this kind of problem?

Comment: Why not check if each succeeding element is larger than the previous element (and delete it if it's not)?

Comment: @ASGM: Because that "greedy" algorithm does not give the _longest_ ascending sub-array. Consider: `9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the [longest increasing subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) problem. There is an [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#Efficient_algorithms) that solves it in O(n log n) time.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! What a difference it makes to know the correct terms to search for ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is one O(NlogN) algorithm from the site which is faster than the recursive algorithm .

http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Longest_Increasing_Subsequence