# Shifting Number Array to the Left but Sorted

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have a number array such as: `[1,2,3,3,3,4,4,8]`, and I delete the element 2 , my goal is to keep the array in order but shift the values by one keeping the duplicates. So the result I would be looking for is: `[1,2,2,2,3,3,4]`. I'm treating all duplicates as a group of numbers.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is not a free coding service. What have you tried? What are you stuck on?

Comment: why you are adding 2 in array why not 5 or 6

Comment: are you using javascript or java? you tag both but they aren't the same...

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876796/removing-elements-to-sort-array

Comment: How do you get from 1,2,3,3,3,4,4,8 to 1,2,2,2,3,3,4 when you delete the second element??

Comment: if you delete 2, you get 1,3,3,3,4,4,8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the original question with grouping values and getting this result, by setting for a group the last value, then this proposal works for it.

> ```
> 1 2 3 3 3 4 4 8
> 1   2 2 2 3 3 4
>   ^ remove
> ```

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 8],
    number = 2,
    result = array.reduce(function () {
        var last, next;
        return function (r, a) {
            if (last === undefined) {
                if (a === number) {
                    last = a;
                } else {
                    r.push(a);
                }
            } else {
                if (a === number) {
                    return r;
                }
                if (next === undefined) {
                    next = a;
                }
                if (a !== next) {
                    last = next;
                    next = a;
                }
                r.push(last);
            }
            return r;
        };
    }(), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array#reduce` to filter out the number you want to remove, and shift the groups:

```js
function regroup(arr, numToRemove) {
  var last;
  var current;
  
  return arr.reduce(function(r, num) {
    if(current !== undefined && num !== current) {
      last = current;
      current = num;
    }
    
    if(last !== undefined) {
      r.push(last);
    } else if(num === numToRemove) {
      current = num;
    } else {
      r.push(num);
    }
    
    return r;
  }, []);
}

var arr = [1,2,3,3,3,4,4,8, 25, 25, 25, 30, 30, 31];

var result = regroup(arr, 2);

console.log('origin: ', JSON.stringify(arr));
console.log('result: ', JSON.stringify(result));
```